# In place usage of C++ <algorithm> algorithms

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

Several STL algorithms have the general form:

```
Algorithm(InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1, OutputIterator result,...)
```

or

```
Algorithm(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1, InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2, OutputIterator result,...)
```

My question is - when can the `OutputIterator result` be in the range `(first1,last1)` or `(first2,last2)`?

For `transform` the answer I found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/

But there are multiple others that may make sense, e.g. `set_difference` should theoretically be safe for such a usage and also it works in code with GCC 4.7.1.

Any references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no general answer for all algorithms. For `set_difference` you can learn from C++11 25.4.5.4/2 that:

`Requires: The resulting range shall not overlap with either of the original ranges.` This seems to make your code undefined behavior that seems to do what you want.

You'll just have to look at the requirements for a particular algorithm before you decide what iterator ranges to use.